# media screen and min-width: 965px and max-width: 965px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 965px){
   //style here
}
@media screen and (max-width: 965px){
   //some other style
}
```

every thing works fine in less than or more than 965px but when the screen on 965px bugs appear

is there is any way to fix that

Comment: Can you detail the problem with some images or at least the code? Dunno if this can be the problem but since both min-width and max-width has the same value, it may join both properties values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the second one to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 964px){
```

that way the y will be kept seperated and won't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 4):

Switch the order and give yourself 1px of leeway between the 2.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 964px){
   //some style
}   


@media screen and (min-width: 965px){
   //style here
}
```

This way, there is no overlap.

Note: It is not recommended to use bot min and max width in screen size queries.  If you just use min-width, and list them from smallest to largest, the one below will override the one above it.